# Warning: include_once, failed to open stream: Permission denied

Tags: php, permissions, include, require, selinux

Server: Centos 6

I have set permissions on this dev server to `0777` all the way back to the home folder (`/home/`...)

changed the owner to apache all all files

> SELINUX is disabled

Still, when running script from browser, I get:

> Warning: include_once(/home/..._somthing.php): failed to open stream:
>   Permission denied

I can only execute as root from the command line.

help?

Comment: check the file permission and  change it to 644.

Comment: Make sure that recursive permission you applied.

Comment: _I can only execute as root from the command line._ **Only** Wow thats a odd ways of saying I am the Super User, and have persissions to really screw things up

Comment: @sAcH: yes, permissions were set recursively to 777.

Comment: @RiggsFolly: It's a dev server in an enclosed local environment. We're just troubleshooting. This is not a place where things will be out in the world

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Failed to open stream : No such file or directory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36577020/failed-to-open-stream-no-such-file-or-directory)